# Unity ar.core.depth show unsuppported on device via bundle but works with apk

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore

I have application with AR features, I mostly tested by generating apk and installing on device, and everything works fine, I tested on Galaxy Tab a7.
But now I want to publish in google play, I create app bundle, and in bundle explorer it shows that Galaxy Tab A7 is unsupported because of these 2 features:

android.hardware.camera.ar

com.google.ar.core.depth

I tried to set it to required="false" but then I got error:

> The ArCore
> dependency type com.google.ar.core is missing from
> AndroidManifest.xml, although the meta-data tag
> com.google.ar.core.min_apk_version has been specified.

But I didn't found any min_apk_version in any files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason changes in Android Studio didn't help. But when I made changes in

Unity->Project Settings->XR Plugin Management

ARCore,ArKit to optional instead required

And export project for Android Studio, with "Export for App Bundle" option it became fine.

I uploaded new bundle to Play Console, and list of devices increased.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue for weeks: my app was not considered compatible on my Galaxy A6 although I've always tested the app on it through direct apk build.

Contacted support but it didn't help (at first they were convinced I was misspelling the app name in the search bar, only after many email they recognised a compatibility problem but without addressing me). I checked and rechecked my Player Settings without luck.

I was about to give up and then I came here and figured out that my "mistake" was to build the app bundle release directly from Unity. It seems that some Player Settings are not properly transferred on the App Bundle release (the aab file) when built directly from Unity. So, as suggested, I tried to export on Android Studio checking Export Project and Export for App Bundle in Build Settings. Then I opened the exported project with Android Studio changing the build type from debug to release (it is another "ghost setting" not transferred by Unity). So I built the project with Android Studio, uploaded on Play Store and volà, hundreds of devices now compatible.

I think Google and Unity Technology really need to syncronize the way they handle app bundle builds..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).